# Facebook canvas: Content in IFrame is truncated in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, facebook

Our Facebook canvas app encounters one problem in IE7 and IE8. The Canvas cannot grow its height which results in content truncated. In the meantime, we found some js errors: 
"Object doesn't support this property or method" xd_arbiter.php?version=6, line 19 character 548

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()` function provided by the Facebook JavaScript SDK - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
});
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
```

> Note: this method is only enabled when Canvas Height is set to "Fixed
>   at (800)px" in the App Dashboard.
>
> Starts or stops a timer which will grow your iframe to fit the content
>   every few milliseconds. Default timeout is 100ms.